# How to load 3D models and textures in Qt creator 2.1 using obj files

Tags: qt

I am getting difficulty in loading 3D models and textures in Qt creator 2.1 while using obj files.It would be really helpful if someone could provide me the examples or material showing how to load 3D models and textures in Qt using obj files.

regards

hurr[i]cane

Answer (score 0):

The Qt Demo has an example program, which shows a 3D Qt logo. As I remember, that logo is a obj 3D file loaded into that program. you can check out that source code.

there are also other Qt demo programs that load textures.